# how to make slider value send as its being changed with flask Socket IO?

Tags: python, jquery, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

problem:

edit:
the slider value is only sent to the server when I release the slider, I want it to send the value as soon is it is changed,also the slider jumps back to the center every time its released and I want it to stay in the position I move it to.

I have an html slider that sends its value to a flask app, it kind of works when you drag and release the mouse.

however I want it send the value of the slider as it is being changed, as well as have the slider stay in the position it was changed to (right now it always jumps back to the center no matter what)

I'm wondering if this is some sort of limitation with modern browsers (I'm using chrome) because it works with internet explorer, although the slider doesn't exactly display correctly.

I tried adding some jquery that should set the slider to the value it was moved to but that doesn't seem to be working.

flask app code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "AFN123"
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template("index.html", min=0, max=100)


@socketio.on('custom_event')
def handle_message(val):
    print('value :' + val)
    emit('custom_event', val, broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

html/javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>slider</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input id="myRange" type="range"  min="1" max="100" value="" class="slider" >
</div>
<div id = "slider_values">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('User has connected!');
    });

    $('#myRange').on('change', function() {
        socket.emit('custom_event',$('#myRange').val());
        $('#myRange').val('');
    });
        socket.on('custom_event', function(val) {
        $("#myRange").attr("value",val);
        $("#slider_values").empty();
        $("#slider_values").append('<li>'+val+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

package versions:

this might be useful too since I was struggling to get socket io to work correctly I had to install various versions of the following packages

```
Flask==2.1.1
Flask-SocketIO==4.0.0
python-engineio==3.2.0
python-socketio==4.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.3
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the problem is the slider value is only sent to the server when I release the slider, I want it to send the value as soon is it is changed.

Comment: also the slider jumps back to the center everytime and I want it to stay in the position I move it to

Comment: You are erasing the sliders range as soon as you send it to the server.  What do you expect that to do, if not snap back to the center?  And you do NOT really want to make a sliders value depend on feedback from a server.  Network delays would make that a horrible user experience.

Comment: its just going to be used locally  I want to use it to control servos on a robot arm it doesn't need to be perfect. also I  thought I was setting the  value with $("#myRange").attr("value",val);